# Merging a vector layer with a Raster layer

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, aerial-photography

I have a Tiff file that has an aerial view and also a shapefile which has contours of the same area.  How can I put the contours in the tiff file so that you can view the TIFF and see them both in one picture.

I am using QGIS.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You Can try rasterize over in processing toolbox. It's a gdal algorithm.

Comment: Is your tif file georeferenced such that the contours properly show over it in QGIS?  If so save you could then save that view to a georeferenced tif via File - Save As Image and selecting tif.  It may not be as high a resolution tif though.  If you need more resolution you could create a map and in map composer's export settings check save world file.

Comment: @johns Both my contours, and my TIFF are in the same spot.  They are georeferenced correctly.

Comment: I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor. For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Comment: I had a similar problem when I started using QGIS.  The answers I received may be helpful to you.  
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/204111/how-to-control-line-width-when-merging-vector-files-into-raster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bring in a shapefile of your contours and make sure they have an elevation attribute with them.  Go to Raster > Conversion > Rasterize and select your shapefile, the elevation attribute, and then your existing Tiff file you want to put the contours on.  Press run and you will get a tiff with the contours on top of the layer.  The following link is very helpful to accomplish this : [How to control line width when merging vector files into raster?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/204111/how-to-control-line-width-when-merging-vector-files-into-raster) .

Thank you @Pooneil